# Do I install KB2600088 on the developer's machine or the web server?

Tags: windows, knowledge-base

Whilst trying to find the solution to a problem on one of my UAT servers which prevented IE10 from working with our ASP.NET app, I found an excellent article by [Scott Hansleman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) explaining how to fix it.

One of the developers followed the [instructions to fix it in a single project](http://nuget.org/packages/App_BrowsersUpdate). We tested this, deployed it to UAT and it worked, but Scott's article recommended installing [KB2600088](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088).

I don't want to have to install this on any unnecessary machines, so my question is: Do I apply this to each developer's machine, or to my UAT environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any machine with IIS that will have IE10 clients.

Comment: FYI, this hotfix has been rolled up in the following patch: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600217